# Excel get the range of Cells beneath a cell that match criteria

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

```
0. A,       B,             C
1. Level,   Name,          Std Dev
2. -1,      Total,         88.80
3. 0,       Commodity,     367.31
4. 1,       Option,        582.81
5. 2,       DBA,           582.81
6. 1,       Commodity,     20.91
7. 2,       Opt,           884.03
8. 2,       opt2,          176.50
9. 0,       Credit Risk,   753.43
10. 1,      Option 2,      753.43
11. 2,      DBA,           474.54
12. 2,      DBA,           747.83
12. 2,      DBA,           553.45
```

Hi above is a transcript of a spreadsheet that I have. I want to for each value that is 0 e.g. Commodity, Credit Risk. I want to add all the values in the std dev column where the value is equal to 2. Until the value changes back to 0.  So commodity being one header will be the sum of DBA, Opt, opt2.
SO Commodity = SUM(582.81 + 884.03 + 176.50).

Hope this makes sense any help greatly appreciated. Kind regards.

Comment: I dont' quite understand what you want, but look at SUMIF and pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables to have a formula do the calculations. If you had the same number of levels under each zero value then you write a SUMIF formula =SUMIF(A:A,"=0", C4:C5)

That would assume you only have two levels below the zero value. If you have more you could just expand the sum range. Once you have that you could copy/paste the formula to the level zero cells.

If you have to have variable levels under the zero you would have to write separate formula for each level zero.

Comment: Thanks for you reply yes thats my problem is that the levels can change the only consistency is the numbering of the levels :(